# Update XML node attribute

Tags: php, xml, setattribute

I'm trying the following without success. Anyone who can help me out about why the attribute imageId is not changed?

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($appCom_file_name);
$frames = $dom->getElementsByTagName('frame');
foreach ($frames as $frame) {
    if ($frame->getAttribute('imageId') == '') {
        $frame->setAttribute('imageId', $id);
    } 
}

$dom->saveXML();
```

XML source:

```
<template>
    <appCom>
        <page>
            <defaultValues>
                <frame id="frame_01_0" deltaRotation="0" deltaScale="100" deltaX="0" deltaY="0" imageId="" />
                <frame id="frame_02_0" deltaRotation="0" deltaScale="100" deltaX="0" deltaY="0" imageId="" />
                <frame id="frame_03_0" deltaRotation="0" deltaScale="100" deltaX="0" deltaY="0" imageId="" />
            </defaultValues>
        </page>
        <page>
            <defaultValues>
                <frame id="frame_01_1" deltaRotation="0" deltaScale="100" deltaX="0" deltaY="0" imageId="" />
                <frame id="frame_02_1" deltaRotation="0" deltaScale="100" deltaX="0" deltaY="0" imageId="" />
                <frame id="frame_03_1" deltaRotation="0" deltaScale="100" deltaX="0" deltaY="0" imageId="" />
            </defaultValues>
        </page>
    </appCom>
</template>
```

Comment: Try with referenced foreach `foreach ($frames as &$frame)`

Comment: Thanks @Justinas for your quick response, but it did not help. Any other idea?

Comment: And when you print out something inside that `if`, it's displayed?

Comment: @Justinas Yes it's displayed, I have tried that to see how far it works. It loops through all nodes correctly and prints whatever is inside the if, but the attribute is not changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all feeback!

It should not output anything but save the file again. ID was of course defined but I forgot to include it with my question. This works now:

```
$id = 1;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML(file_get_contents($appCom_file_name));
$frames = $dom->getElementsByTagName('frame');
foreach ($frames as $frame) {
    if ($frame->getAttribute('imageId') == '') {
        $frame->setAttribute('imageId', $id);
    } 
}

$dom->save($appCom_file_name);
```

Comment: @silkfire I was using $dom->saveXML() instead of $dom->save(). And i'm also using file_get_contents() when loading the XML-file.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code and obviously, I'm getting an error that `$id` is not defined. Have you tried changing this line:

```
$frame->setAttribute('imageId', $id);
```

to this:

```
$frame->setAttribute('imageId', $frame->getAttribute('id'));
```

?

And of course, to print the results to the screen you would use `echo`:

```
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you must use saveXML with parametr... here is my code for inspiration:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($datas);

$svg = $dom->getElementsByTagName('svg');                        
$resize = $this->resize(452, 480, $res);
$svg->item(0)->setAttribute('width', $resize['w']);  
$svg->item(0)->setAttribute('height', $resize['h']); 
$datas = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" tandalone="no"?>'.$dom->saveXML($svg->item(0));
```